# Run multiple functions together in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to do sorting visualization. I have done 3 visualizations of the bubble, quick and merge sort. When I run these sorting happens one after other. How to run all the three functions at a time so that I can compare all three.

This is the general form that I have done,

```py
def OnClick():
   BubbleSort(parameters)
   QuickSort(parameters)
   MeregeSort(parameters)
```

I want all the three functions to run at a time.

Comment: Can you send the full code?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a step function for each algorithm and just run in a loop and visualize one step at a time for each algorithm.
Consider maintaining the state of the algorithm in a state object if required.

### Edit

I can offer an implementation that is fairly simple for that:
Let's use boublesort for example.
Create a BoublesortVisualizer object, and define a step function that is implemented by running boublesort from some step during the algorithm one step forward (let's say, every loop).
for knowing which step you are in, maintain some state in the class.
Do the same for the other sorting algorithms.

now, run a loop in your OnClick function which invokes the step function for every sorting function you have.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `multiprocessing` using `import multiprocessing` or `import concurrent.futures`

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html , Docs for `multiprocessing`
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html , Docs for `concurrent.futures`

Comment: multiprocessing is not what he is looking for, he wants to visualize them together, not run the computation in parallel.

Comment: Yes, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the three functions in separate threads:

```py
import threading

def OnClick():
    for func in (BubbleSort, QuickSort, MergeSort):
        threading.Thread(target=func, args=(parameters,), daemon=True).start()
```